# Calculated Column Formula Calendar

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-calendar, calculated-column-formula

I have three columns in my calendar on SharePoint 2013.  They are:

- Truck Number
- Trailer Number
- Service Type

I am currently using a calculated formula column that states; `=[Truck Number]&" "&[Service Type]` so now on my calendar when someone selects from drop down of Truck and service it comes up on the calendar.  How do I add into this formula the Trailer number if the user happens to select it?  Thanks all!

Comment: where do you want it? at the end?

Comment: =[Truck Number]&" "&[Service Type]&" "&[Service Number]

Answer (score 2):

I presume your issues is the `[Trailer Number]` field is a **Lookup** field, and Lookup fields can not be referenced in a Calculated Column.

A workaround is to create a SharePoint Designer workflow which *on Item Change* takes the value from the `[Trailer Number]` Lookup field and writes it to another **Text** field, which you can then reference in your Formula.